# Missing ) after argument list while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

When I run my code I  get a syntax error returning SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while compiling ejs.

Everywhere I've looked has said it is more than likely a typo but I've scanned through the file for a while now and have yet to find the error. The few questions I've reviewed have had more clear issues such as not closing a statement or something along those lines, however, I've been unable to find such errors in my code. I've included the entire file since I'm unsure where the error may be located.

```
    <!--hero-->

    <div class="hero-cont">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images\logo-transparent.png">
        </div>
        <div class="hero-txt plus-jakarta">
            <h1>Quickly monitor your favorite crypto currencies at a glance</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--top coins-->

    <div class="top-cont">
        <div class="head plus-jakarta">
            <h2>Top Coins</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-cont">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src= <%= first.coins.iconUrl %> >
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Market Cap: <%= first.coins.marketCap %></li>
                        <li>Rank: <%= first.coins.rank %></li>
                        <li>Change: <%= first.coins.change %></li>
                        <li>24hr Volume: <%= first.coins.24hVolume %></li>
                        <li>Price: <%= first.coins.price %></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="carrot">
                    <% if (first.coins.change > 0) { %>
                        <img src='/images/green-carrot.png'>
                    <% } else if (first.coins.change < 0) { %>
                        <img src="/images/red-carrot.png">
                    <% } %>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src= <%= second.coins.iconUrl %> >
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Market Cap: <%= second.coins.marketCap %></li>
                        <li>Rank: <%= second.coins.rank %></li>
                        <li>Change: <%= second.coins.change %></li>
                        <li>24hr Volume: <%= second.coins.24hVolume %></li>
                        <li>Price: <%= second.coins.price %></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="carrot">
                    <% if (second.coins.change > 0) { %>
                        <img src='/images/green-carrot.png'>
                    <% } else if (second.coins.change < 0) { %>
                        <img src="/images/red-carrot.png">
                    <% } %>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src= <%= third.coins.iconUrl %> >
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Market Cap: <%= third.coins.marketCap %></li>
                        <li>Rank: <%= third.coins.rank %></li>
                        <li>Change: <%= third.coins.change %></li>
                        <li>24hr Volume: <%= third.coins.24hVolume %></li>
                        <li>Price: <%= third.coins.price %></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="carrot">
                    <% if (third.coins.change > 0) { %>
                        <img src='/images/green-carrot.png'>
                    <% } else if (third.coins.change < 0) { %>
                        <img src="/images/red-carrot.png">
                    <% } %>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--search-->

    <div class="s-cont">
        <div class="head plus-jakarta">
            <h2>Search</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="res">
            <form action="/search" method="GET">
                <input class="search plus-jakarta" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Coin Name Or Symbol" required>

                <% if (locals.user) { %>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img src= <%= user.coins.iconUrl %> >
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Market Cap: <%= user.coins.marketCap %></li>
                                <li>Rank: <%= user.coins.rank %></li>
                                <li>Change: <%= user.coinss.change %></li>
                                <li>24hr Volume: <%= user.coins.24hVolume %></li>
                                <li>Price: <%= user.coins.price %></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carrot">
                            <% if (user.coins.change > 0) { %>
                                <img src='/images/green-carrot.png'>
                            <% } else if (user.coins.change < 0) { %>
                                <img src="/images/red-carrot.png">
                            <% } %>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% } %>

                <input class="btn plus-jakarta" type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: user.coins.24hVolume

Comment: @DaveNewton What about it? Also I can see the the extra s on user.coins.change that I have fixed lol

Comment: "What about it" is that it's invalid JS and it was what jumped out in the 120-line code dump lol

Comment: That's interpreted as `user.coins; 0.24; hVolume`. The syntax `.24` is a valid number in javascript meaning `0.24`. You either need to do `user.coins["24hVolume"]` or rename that property to `user.coins.twentyFourHourVolume`

Comment: If that was the case I only wanted to know why it is invalid. I apologize for the amount of code but as I stated in the question the error location is simply the ejs file so I wasn't sure where it could be inside the file.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for the explanation, the variable is a response field for an api request but I'll try your first answer.